# Repeating Meteor template with a specific item in mongodb collection

Tags: mongodb, templates, meteor, meteor-blaze

I have a collection with this item:

```
{
  "item1": ["foo", "bar", "baz"],
  "item2": ...
}
```

I made a helper function to repeat a template for each item in `item1`

```
Template.temp.helpers({
  items: function() {
    return Col.find({},{item1:1});
  }
});
```

and this is the template

```
<template name="temp">
  {{#each items}}
    {{> anotherTemplate}}
  {{/each}}
</template>
```

But I get back an empty array. Why doesn't it work?

Comment: Do you publish/subscribe to it correctly?

Also, it should be {{/each}} not {{/items} but I guess you did not pasted it from your code

Comment: @Bennyz The first is a typo, and I'm still with autopublish

Comment: I see, also your helper is on another template (I assume this is a typo as well?)
Did you run the query in the shell to make sure it's correct?

Comment: Your template name in html is not the same in js `<template name="temp">` `Template.test.helpers` is just a typo?

Answer (score 0):

Try with `{{#each items.item1}}`

Because, `Col.find({},{item1:1})` just remove all other field from result.

[Limit Fields to Return from a Query](http://docs.mongodb.org/master/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/)

It's like `SELECT item1 FROM table` in SQL

If you need repeat your template for each item in item1, you need to precise which array should be use.

```
<template name="temp">
  {{#each items.item1}}
    {{> anotherTemplate}}
  {{/each}}
</template>
```

Comment: should work I would've thought: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/spacebars/README.md#path-evaluation

Comment: actually no in your case `items` is _basically_ an array of objects so `items.item1` doesn't make sense (and is undefined - since item1 isn't defined on the array). If you just have the one item in the collection, which then has the various arrays as properties of that object then using `findOne(...)` instead of `find(...)` in the items helper, should solve your problem. Otherwise, if you have multiple documents/objects with multiple item1, item2 arrays see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want:

```
{{#each items}}
    {{#each item1}}
        {{> anotherTemplate}}
    {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```

Or this:

```
Template.temp.helpers({
  items: function() {
    return Col.find({},{item1:1}).map(function(item){
      return item.item1
    })
  }
});
```

That way items will return the item1 array. Originally it was returning an array of objects with just one element, the item1 arrays of each object:

```
[{
     item1: ["foo","bar","baz"]
 },
 {
     item1: ["lah","nah","jah"]
 },
 {
     item1: ["see","gee","bee"]
 }]
```

this way you'll get an array of arrays: `[["foo","bar","baz"], ["lah","nah","jah"], ["see","gee","bee"]]`

Comment: @JobJot thanx, but I'm not sure what it solves, seems unnecessary complicated

Comment: I guess I was just making sure that you were iterating over the array elements, rather than than the objects that contain the arrays item1, was thinking maybe that was your issue. As you describe it you have a collection with objects that contain attributes item1, item 2, yeah? Or is it just one object in the collection that contains the various arrays?

Answer (score 0):

Meteor mongo methods are a little different you cannot use.

```
 return Col.find({},{item1:1});
```

you can use it this way:

```
 return Col.find({},{fields:{'item1':1}});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do return something like this from helper

```
return Col.findOne({}).item1
```

It should work now

Thanks